Is it possible to have an OPTIMISTIC LOCK without "select version as version_ from person where id=?"
I have entity like that:
public class Person {                                             
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private Long id;                                                                       
private String name;  
private int age;  
@Version 
private int version; }
                                                                                        

and method in service like this:
@Transactional 
public Person update(int id, String name) {
Person person = personRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(); 
person.setName(name); 
return person; }

with that lock on repository method:
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC) 
Optional<Person> findById(int id); 

Is it possible to update person with only 2 queries, I mean without query from Optimistic Lock "select version as version_ from person where id=?" after select query and update query.
I know that PESSIMISTIC Lock do not generate this extra query but i do not want to change my lock. I `was tried do this update without @Lock but I think it is not safety.

What DB are you using? Does it even have a mechanism for optimistic locking?

It's MySQL. It supports optimistic locking but I am wondering if it possible to get optimistic locking with @Lock on repo method and have only 2 queries - without query which is sending by hibertnate for optimistic locking - select version as version_ from person where id=?, on the end of transaction

The point of optimistic locking is to be optimistic that you don't need to modify the row upfront at all; JPA will increment the lock value on the update statement automatically. I have no idea why there is that extra fetch for the version value from the DB at all - see if it goes away if you remove the Lock annotation on the find method - but I would guess it is a hibernate implementation detail that is 'refreshing' the lock version field from the DB. It should be unnecessary as it is contained within the entity itself - Other providers don't behave this way.

Why do you think you need that lock annotation exactly? I would remove it, as it will force every 'findById' call to increment the version and so force an update if done in a transaction - even when there are no other changes at all. I doubt that is your intent (though maybe). I am guessing now that you are returning an 'optional', which lets Spring/Hibernate return a proxy object instead of fetching the entity.  The lock annotation then requires incrementing the version, so it fetches that version value separately since that is all it needs. Just a guess as I don't use optional
